# Remote Debugging JRuby in Docker from IntelliJ

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging, intellij-idea, remote-debugging

I have a Ruby On Rails (JRuby) project running in Puma web server running from within a local Docker container. I'm trying to debug the application from IntelliJ running on the same host using Ruby Remote configuration.

Outside of my application Gems, I have added the following to the test/development group:

```
gem 'ruby-debug-base'
gem 'ruby-debug-ide'
```

When I run the command inside the Docker container via my startup script, I am using this command:

```
exec bundle exec rdebug-ide --host 0.0.0.0 --port 1234 --dispatcher-port 26162 -- /usr/local/bundle/gems/puma-3.5.2-java/bin/puma -C /var/www/apps/app1/config/puma.rb
```

When I start my container, I get the following output which seems like the debugger starts up correctly:

```
Fast Debugger (ruby-debug-ide 0.6.0, ruby-debug-base 0.10.3.2, file filtering is not supported) listens on 0.0.0.0:1234
```

When I run the remote debugging in IntelliJ, it seems to start Puma at that time, then it fails with what seems to be a conflict or call into `listen` gem (which I'm using listen '~> 3.1.5').  I see this output, as it seems to not support the event.

```
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 3.5.2 (jruby 9.1.2.0 - ruby 2.3.0), codename: Amateur Raccoon Rocketry
* Min threads: 0, max threads: 16
* Environment: development
Exception in thread "Ruby-0-Thread-2: /usr/local/bundle/gems/listen-3.1.5/lib/listen/internals/thread_pool.rb:6" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unknown event type: thread-begin
     at org.jruby.debug.Util.typeForEvent(Util.java:122)
     at org.jruby.debug.DebugEventHook.eventHandler(DebugEventHook.java:97)
     at org.jruby.runtime.EventHook.event(EventHook.java:30)
     at org.jruby.Ruby.callEventHooks(Ruby.java:3231)
     at org.jruby.runtime.ThreadContext.trace(ThreadContext.java:641)
     at org.jruby.internal.runtime.RubyRunnable.run(RubyRunnable.java:103)
     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "Ruby-0-Thread-3: /usr/local/bundle/gems/listen-3.1.5/lib/listen/internals/thread_pool.rb:6" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unknown event type: thread-begin
     at org.jruby.debug.Util.typeForEvent(Util.java:122)
     at org.jruby.debug.DebugEventHook.eventHandler(DebugEventHook.java:97)
     at org.jruby.runtime.EventHook.event(EventHook.java:30)
     at org.jruby.Ruby.callEventHooks(Ruby.java:3231)
     at org.jruby.runtime.ThreadContext.trace(ThreadContext.java:641)
     at org.jruby.internal.runtime.RubyRunnable.run(RubyRunnable.java:103)
     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
! Unable to load application: Timeout::Error: execution expired
Timeout::Error: execution expired
```

I've tried different versions and no matter what I try I seem to be getting this same thing.  Are there limitations to Ruby remote debugging, is this not compatible with `listen` gem?

I'm using Puma 3.5.2 (platform:jruby), Listen 3.1.5, Ruby 2.3.1p112, JRuby 9.1.2.0, and Ruby 2.3.0.  I'm also running on a VirtualBox VM running Linux Mint, if that makes any difference.  I'm relatively new to Ruby on Rails coming from a Java background, so this could be a newbie thing I'm missing.

Comment: So I got rid of the `listener` gem, and commented out the`config.file_watcher = ActiveSupport::EventedFileUpdateChecker` to get rid of that dependency, now I run I get the same error but coming from Puma.

Comment: Previous comment seems to point to JRuby itself, any thoughts?  JRuby Util.java definitely does not include 'thread-start'.  Am I even using the right debugging libraries at this point?